# Can I use firebase to login user via a phone number and password on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication, passwords

So users to my app will be receiving invite links or joining a waitlist to get an invite. When it comes to logging in, they will login with their phone, email, or username as the identifier, along with a password. Would firebase be able to handle all of this? I have heard you cannot do straight phone/password login unless you do OTP. Is there a way I can customize my firebase to do this or should I explore another auth?

Comment: While phone number + password authentication can be built on top of Firebase, it is not a built-in provider.

Comment: With Firebase, one auth source represents a user account, to do this requires creating two accounts and linking them together. This process typically involves a master account and a linked account.

- Phone setup:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth
- Password Auth:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth

- Auth linking: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking